# Adding poi in wikitude phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, wikitude

I am working on an app in which I've used WikitudeAR Cordova plugin, I've successfully implemented that and app is running fine on the device with no POIs. I want to add POIs in the app, what is the procedure to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the examples and tutorials that are inside the Wikitude SDK package that you have downloaded. Especially the tutorial series should give you a good overview on how to use the Architect API to create objects in AR. [Here](http://forum.wikitude.com/documentation?p_p_id=2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet_mvcPath=/display/view_article.jsp&_2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet_resourcePrimKey=35778) is another quick start guide which shows you what you need to do to create a simple AR experience.